# What is the name of a DE with this form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

apologies if this is basic. (Also apologies, if the tag is incorrect. I think this is a nonlinear DE but I couldn't find a more appropriate tag).

I've been trying to solve a problem that boils down to this equation:

$$\frac{du}{dt} = a_0 - a_1 \cdot u^2(t)$$

where:

- $a_0, a_1$ are constants

Although I am able to solve this numerically (see image below), I have a feeling that there is probably a neat analytical solution which eludes me.

[image]

I expect that this is probably a family of DE, so I  was wondering if someone could provide the name and (even better) the approach for an analytical solution.

---

I don't if this matters, however I've been actually trying to solve the following problem (which I think is equivalent):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = a_0 - a_1 \cdot \left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)^2 \text{ with } u(t) = \frac{d}{dt}x(t)$$

Comment: It's separable.  You just need to integrate $1/(a_0 -a_1u^2)$.

Comment: @B.Goddard So you are saying that I only need to do $\int \frac{1}{a_0-a_1 u^2}du$, which yields $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_0 a_1}} arctanh(\sqrt{\frac{a_1}{a_0} u })$? This is embarrassing. Thank you for your time. I would gladly have you turn your comment to a answer in order to accept it.

Comment: Yep.  But this assumes $a_0$ and $a_1$ are positive.

Comment: yeap they are both real, positive quantities.